# Why do these "Black Blobs" appear within very tiny spaces in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, shaders, shader-nodes

I have a shader which uses a massive array of planes mixed with a transparent BSDF to render 3D / Procedural textures, such as this marble fractal..

However, cycles appears to render these odd "black blobs" inside the center of the planes.

This doesnt just happen with my 3D texture, just having a transparent array of planes creates this weird internal blackness.

Ive seen people use this technique before.... so I have no idea why its suddenly not working, it used to, but now its creating these weird black spaces.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Render Properties tab, under Light Paths > Max Bounces > Transparent. Increase the max bounces for transparency.

[image]

EDIT:

I just realised you have 400 planes with transparency which is excessive. Im assuming you havn't used volumetrics before. So instead of faking volumetic shading, use real volumetric shading instead.

[image]

Comment: Volumetrics wont work for this high level of precision (An extremely high detail marble fractal), its the reason Im using an array of planes. Also, I needed even higher precision, and the max bounces (1024) isnt enough to fully erase the black bits, so I might just edit the source code and let me bypass the limit. The cloudy appearance of volumes just doesnt work for what I want to do.

Comment: You can increase the volume step rate in the render properties. Also set the max volume bounce to 1. You can get pretty sharp results. These are 2 cubes, one rotated , both with different procedural volume shaders. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9c0K.png @MisterSirCode

Comment: Alright, I might give it a shot, thanks